# Como clonar repositorio de gitlab sin que pida contraseña

Tags: linux, git, gitlab

Lo que estoy haciendo es clonando un proyecto de mi cuenta de gitlab pero al hacerlo me pide un usuario y contraseña pero para los fines que lo estoy ocupando no me sirve eso por que lo estoy haciendo dentro de un script de bash y no quiero que sea interactivo como puedo configurar gitlab para que no me pida el usuario y contraseña.

PD: estoy ocupando https para clonar el proyecto.

Comment: tanto para gitlab como para github, se las denomina deploy keys. Si no lo especificas sólo pueden leer (clone/pull) pero también les podes dar permiso de escritura (push) https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/README.html#deploy-keys para un proyecto en particular (gitlab) página principal del repo -> settings->repository->deploy keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes conectarte a Gitlab mediante SSH, solo debes generar las llaves (en caso que no las hayas creado antes) en tu directorio _ ~/.ssh_ mediante el siguiente comando:

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "tuemail@dominio.com"
```

El comando anterior genera un par de llaves: pública y privada; ahora solo debes copiar el contenido de la llave pública (i.e. **id_rsa.pub**) y agregarlo en la sección ***SSH Keys*** dentro de ***Profile Settings*** en tu cuenta de Gitlab.

Es importante que el script que utilices para conectarte al repositorio se ejecute bajo el usuario sobre el que generaste el par de llaves.